# Scala, Akka and Durable Scheduler

Tags: scala, akka, scheduling, persistent

My job is to implement small microservice in Scala/Akka(let's call it RSI), responsible for making some periodical HTTP requests. Basic flow is as follows:

1. RSI receives message via AMQP.
2. This message should trigger some periodical HTTP requests to other microservice(until positive response, with some cancellation strategy, i.e. quit after 10 negative responses).
3. If any of the above calls were successfull, another periodical HTTP requests have to be made(some kind of long-polling), again until successfull response(or cancellation).

It's straightforward, if you don't have to make scheduling durable. Unfortunately, I have to.

Any ideas? On my first attempt, I've created 3 actors(SchedulerActor, and the other two, RequestActors), and plan to use durable messagebox. However, it turned out it's not sufficient. Another solution is to use akka-camel-quartz, but I'm not sure, whether it's persistable.

Comment: Maybe you can take a look to akka-persistence and create some logic that will let you continue with your schedules even if something fails. Take a look: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/persistence.html

Comment: Indeed, I thought about it. The plan was to create RequestActor, that will schedule itself, but in order to make it work after JVM crash, some kind of magic with preStart method must be done. I'm not sure, whether this solution is as clean as I wish to :) Or maybe I'm wrong, and other solution could be proposed, using akka-persistence